# React streamich / react-use upsert example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to update a list in a react component using react-use upsert function.

```
const [aList, { upsert: upsertAList }] = useList({id: 0, name: 'Foo'});
```

The documentation say:
upsert: (predicate: (a: T, b: T) => boolean, newItem: T) => void; — Like updateFirst but in case of predicate miss - pushes item to the list.
But it doesn't help me.

Can anyone give me an example how to use it?
let elem = {id:1, name: 'Bar'}
I would like to upload the element in the list with the new one.

`upsertAList(____) // <- what hould I write here instead of '____'?`

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Why you can ask and answer within exactly ONE second??

Comment: I was looking for an answer, I asked some colleagues, while I was editing the question here in stackoverflow. While editing the answer here, a colleague of mine replied me with the solution. So I wrote it here: Q&A at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [aList, { upsert: upsertAList }] = useList({id: 0, name: 'Foo'});
let repElem = {id: 0, name: 'bar'};
upsert( (a,b) => { if (a.id === b.id) return true }, newElem );
```